# How to mount a gpg-encrypted tar archive file?

Tags: mount, tar, gpg

On my laptop I actually have a folder where I store personal data which I don't want to share:

```
private_folder
├── baz
│   └── secret_file_3
└── foo
    └── bar
        ├── secret_file_1
        └── secret_file_2
```

But in case my laptop was stolen, I want this data to be protected by encryption.

My favourite taste about this, would be to archive then encrypt my folder, like this:

```
$ tar -cf private_folder.tar private_folder
$ gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo AES256 private_folder.tar
$ rm -r private_folder private_folder.tar
```

Then I would like this encrypted tar file to be mountable, with read/write access on runtime, in
order to use its content as any other directory.

I know it's easy to mount a simple tar file (i.e. with `archivemount`), but what about a gpg-encrypted tar file?

Comment: Found this link a bit late https://superuser.com/questions/926754/how-to-mount-a-encrypted-tar-file-in-linux, will give feedback if something interesting happened

Comment: Roughly how much data is stored? If there's a lot you might want to consider an encrypted volume using LUKS since random access isn't a strong point of `tar`

Comment: @Torin not very much data: something between Kb and a few Mb